# Flutter - dynamic toggle buttons with dynamic state variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create toggle buttons dynamically according to a set of data got from server.
It requires me to create state select variables dynamically as well and thus they can not be used directly in onPressed event.

I use "catching variable" technic but toggle buttons does not change their state on clicking even they change their boolean state variables

```
Map<String, List<bool>> toggleButtonValues = new Map<String, List<bool>>();
List<Widget> toggleButtons = new List<Widget>();

  void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gl.allfeatures.length; i++) {
      List<Widget> rowcat = new List<Widget>();
      Text category =
          new Text("Select Options - " + gl.allfeatures[i]["category"]);
      rowcat.add(category);
      toggleButtons.add(new Row(children: rowcat));
      List<Widget> tbrow;
      for (int c = 0; c < gl.allfeatures[i]["features"].length; c++) {
        if (c % 2 == 0) {
          tbrow = new List<Widget>();
          toggleButtons.add(new Row(children: tbrow));
        }

        toggleButtonValues.addEntries([
          new MapEntry<String, List<bool>>(
              toggleButtonValues.length.toString(), new List<bool>())
        ]);
        toggleButtonValues.entries.last.value.add(true);
        var ltl=toggleButtonValues.entries.last;
        ToggleButtons tb = new ToggleButtons(
          children: [new Text(gl.allfeatures[i]["features"][c]["name"])], 
          isSelected: toggleButtonValues.entries.last.value,
          onPressed: (index)=>
          setState((){
            ltl.value[0]^=true;
          }
          ),);

        tbrow.add(tb);
      }
    }

  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _context,
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 82.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: toggleButtons,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton:
            Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            height: 8,
            child: new Divider(
              height: 0.0,
              thickness: 2,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0, left: 0.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 5.0),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: new FloatingActionButton.extended(
                        label: Text('Back'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        heroTag: "btnBack"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      label: Text('To Description'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/cardescription");
                      },
                      heroTag: "btnDescription"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]));
  }
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this case?

**UPDATE #1:**
DartPad example : https://dartpad.dev/a2800ad9c84c55e701bee17d0594c6d6

**SOLUTION:** my problem was in initialization lists in build method, should be separated and initialized in the initState method.

Comment: @pskink if you were looking more percisely into my code you would see that every toggle button has single state variable and single list entry and thus there is no need for index

Comment: @pskink "dynamically" means "on the fly" and has been used forever in software development world - not sure what is not clear here for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate `ToggleButtons` from data source.

```
  List<List<IconData>> source;
  List<List<bool>> values;

  Iterable<Widget> generateToggleButtons() sync* {
    for (var index = 0; index < source.length; index += 1) {
      final children = source[index].map((value) => Icon(value)).toList();
      final isSelected = values[index];

      yield ToggleButtons(
        children: children,
        isSelected: isSelected,
        onPressed: (index) {
          setState(() {
            isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
          });
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

```
    source = [
      [Icons.ac_unit, Icons.call, Icons.cake],
      [Icons.access_alarm, Icons.backspace, Icons.calendar_today],
      [Icons.dashboard, Icons.edit, Icons.face],
    ];

    values = List.generate(
      source.length,
      (index) => List.generate(source.length, (index) => true),
    );
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e2fbcc69547ee6e9f5022e35a596011c)

Comment: Thank you for the example, but for some reason, my buttons still not switch their states https://dartpad.dev/a2800ad9c84c55e701bee17d0594c6d6

Comment: Don't initialize `toggleButtonValues`  in `build`.